# Android save uri to database and then use it again later

Tags: android, image, sqlite, uri

I have two activities the second is where you enter the data and select an image and the first or main activity is where that data is displayed. The code for the image picker looks as follows:

```
imagePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Image Selector"), 1);
        }
    });
```

And then the data is is handled in the onActivityResult method

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
imagePicker.setImageURI(uri);
imageUri = uri.toString();
```

imagePicker has its image set to show the user the response and imageUri is a global String variable. When the user has filled in the form and pressed the add button the imageUri String and a few other variables are inserted into a row of a database table. This activity closes and inside the main activities onResume method the data is retrieved and each row of the database table equates to an item in the list view.

As I have a custom list view item layout I have used a custom array adapter. In the adapter the imageUri String variable becomes object.getImage().

```
if(!object.getImage().equals("")) {
    imageView.setImageUri(Uri.parse(object.getImage()));
}
```

I check if it has a value because the image isn't required from the user and so a standard image is displayed. If they have selected an image it will set the image uri from the uri string. This is where my problem is becuase when it is run the area where the image is meant to be is blank and I get the error:

```
resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A29948
```

I am inclined to believe that is something of a combination of the error and the list view because right after the form activity is completed and close and the item is visible in the list view without scrolling the image is how it is meant to be but as soon as I open another activity or open the app again they all go blank. Even when the image is showing though I believe I still get the same store of error message

Comment: The URI permissions you get from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` only last until the receiving Activity is destroyed. You'll need to save the image locally or use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` with `takePersistableUriPermission()` if you want persistent access to a URI from another app.

Comment: See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Documents/Durable) for an example of what Mr. Lake is referring to: taking persistable permissions (where available) or making a private copy.

Comment: That sample app has been really useful, thank you. My only concern is the private copy, once the user is done with that picture how does one delete it so unneeded images don't just accumulate?